# jQuery if date true, change class of element x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Now I have two more questions and have updated my code.

1. I have this if (releaseDate <= today), why is the Date 15.05.2015 success?!
2. When I want to check dates with time example: 25.04.2015 - 09.00 am, how  can I check that with today and when date is over 25.04.2015 == true.

My code:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
var releaseDate = {};

jQuery(".state").each(function() {
 releaseDate = jQuery(this).text() 
    
 var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 var hh = today.getHours();
  
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 
 var today = dd+'.'+mm+'.'+yyyy; 
  
 if (releaseDate <= today) {
   jQuery(this).parent().next().find('span.label').addClass('label-success').removeClass('label-warning');
   jQuery(this).parent().next().find('span.label').text('Online');
 }     
  });
</script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center" valign="middle"><strong>Shop</strong></th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle"><strong>Date</strong></th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle"><strong>Status</strong></th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle"><strong>Link</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">LINK</a></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="state">15.05.2015</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="label label-warning">Upcoming</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"><strong>LINK <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span></strong></a></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">LINK</a></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="state">25.04.2015</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="label label-warning">Upcoming</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"><strong>LINK <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span></strong></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">LINK</a></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="state">30.04.2015</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><span class="label label-warning">Upcoming</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" title="#" target="_blank"><strong>LINK <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span></strong></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope someone can explain or show me that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (releaseDate == today) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('span.label')
        .addClass('label-success').removeClass('label-warning');
}
```

Does what you want. [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/o48zxefj/1/).

[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) are fairly self explanatory. 
[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) goes to the surrounding `<tr>` element, [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) get the immediately following siblings, and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) looks for a span with a class of label in this instance.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I was creating the fiddle and typing up the answer before the other was created. I got ninja'd :). I've left it for the links though.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you want to change the class of the `span` in the next table cell `td`. You can use `$(this).parent().next()` to get to that cell, and use `.find('.label')` to locate the `span` that you want to change the class for.

Then, you can use either the combination of `removeClass()` and `addClass()` or just `toggleClass()` methods:

```
if (releaseDate == today) { 
    $(this).parent().next().find('.label').removeClass('label-warning').addClass('label-success');  
    //or possible
    $(this).parent().next().find('.label').toggleClass('label-warning label-success');              
}
```

Comment: You could add some explanation for the OP to understand what is happening.